# centos 6.4 login as root error

Tags: linux, ssh

I have just installed CentOS 6.4 and cannot log in as root over ssh from other computer. Option **PermitRootLogin** in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is set to **yes**, and service sshd is restarted. Any suggestion?

Comment: What output you have when trying to login?

Comment: Try adding more details about the error. Also, I think this should be moved to serverfault.

Comment: Try to `ssh -v` & also look in the server's log files.

Comment: Can you log in from root on a console ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following logfiles:

```
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
```

It could be that the permissions are wrong on some file or directory on the server. There are many possibilities. The best thing would be to look for the clue in those logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the port for SSH is "listening"? Do a netstat -ant and look if there is any reference to default port for SSH(22), assuming you are using it. If there isn't any reference to it try to create a new rule in the firewall.